# Submit YARN jobs to remote Hadoop cluster via socks proxy

Tags: hadoop, proxy, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to access a firewalled Hadoop cluster running YARN via a SOCKS proxy. The cluster itself is not using proxied connections -- only my client running on a local machine (e.g. a laptop) is connected via `ssh -D 9999 user@gateway-host` to a machine that can see the Hadoop cluster.

In the Hadoop configuration `core-site.xml` (on my laptop) I have the following lines:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.socks.server</name>
    <value>localhost:9999</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.net.SocksSocketFactory</value>
</property>
```

Accessing HDFS this way works great. However, when I try to submit a YARN job, it fails and I can see in the logs that the nodes are not able to talk to each other:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection refused; Host Details : local host is: "host1"; destination host is: "host2":8030; 
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
```

where `host1` and `host2` are both parts of the hadoop cluster.

I guess what is happening is that the hadoop nodes are trying to communicate via a socks proxy as well and this is obviously failing since no proxy server exists on each host. Is there a way to fix this apart from setting up a dedicated proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the Hadoop nodes must not use the SOCKS proxy for the communication. You can achieve that by marking the SocketFactory setting on the cluster side *final*.

In `core-site.xml` on the cluster, add the *final* tag to the default SocketFactory property:

```
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.net.StandardSocketFactory</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
```

Obviously, you must restart cluster services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I've actually figured this out in the meantime, and it works fine for hadoop MapReduce jobs, but not for Spark jobs. For the latter, it seems that Spark is ignoring the "final" setting for the socket factory class, since it's still trying to communicate using the proxy. I've opened a spark jira about it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9825 but so far no response